# Optimize/Beautify Boolean Statement in Specific Code

Tags: java

I have the following code and am wondering if this can be further optimized and also beautified (in order to be more readable) :

```
if( ( subType = entry.getSubType() ) ==null
    || 
    !(subType.equals("typeA") || subType.equals("typeB"))
    ||
    ( version>=5 &&  (subType.equals("typeA") || subType.equals("typeB")) )
    ||
    (       version>=4 &&  subType.equals("typeA") )
    ) 
arrayData.add(entry);
```

Comment: @jamal please inform as to which of the criteria were used in order to decide that the question is off-topic? I'm quite eager and curious. That is the specific section of code I wanted reviewed and it's quite explanatory what they do. You cannot expect someone to upload their whole project or classes to code review in order to be "concrete". Declaring this is not a concrete section of code for review is completely subjective based on the help center rules. Or do we need to upload a full application? I could package that in public static main for you if that makes it concrete :D...

Comment: This isn't even a complete function. We don't do stub code, as explained in the close header. We don't have enough context to see what you want. Why we don't deal in questions without context can be read [here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1710/52915).

Comment: Actually, it's pretty clear, considering the generality of the question as well as the naming and sample size.  If you have actual code, even something partial that works on its own, then you're welcome to post that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@HostileFork is completely right.  From a code review perspective, your code should be optimized for readability.

It could be a little more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
WhateverType subType = entry.getSubType();
boolean isTypeA = (subType == null) ? false : subType.equals("typeA");
boolean isTypeB = (subType == null) ? false : subType.equals("typeB");

//What should be added ? 
if ( ( !isTypeA && !isTypeB    )  // Anything other than A and B should be 
   ||( version >= 4 && isTypeA )  // Type A for version 4 and over should be
   ||( version >= 5 && isTypeB )) // Type B for version 5 and over should be
  arrayData.add(entry);
```

Note that this code is 9 lines as well, but readable.

Comment: +1 for saying I'm right.  :-)  I wanted to introduce a variable just to show that the per-version logic could be more complex and not force one into a single `if` statement, but I've expanded and made that more explicit...

Comment: `"typeA".equals(subType)` will allow you to skip the null checks, assuming `subType` is a string and not a different class with a special `equals`

Answer (score 3):

I don't really do Java.  But this looks like infrequently executed code that you should be optimizing for readability vs. trying to minimize the number of comparisons.

Imagine being in the position of someone maintaining the code after a directive like *"we've decided not to support versions prior to 4."*  Is it completely clear which part they can delete?

So how do you convey the intention of this code (essentially, a version-sensitive decision on whether or not to add an entry to arrayData based on a type?)  You want to distinguish between versions prior to 4, version 4, and version 5 and above.  Imagine breaking it down so each branch is clearly separated:

```
boolean shouldAdd = false;

WhateverType subType = entry.getSubType();
boolean isTypeA = (subType == null) ? false : subType.equals("typeA");
boolean isTypeB = (subType == null) ? false : subType.equals("typeB");

if (!isTypeA && !isTypeB)
    shouldAdd = true;

if (version >= 4) { 
    if (isTypeA)
        shouldAdd = true;
}

if (version >= 5) {
    if (isTypeB)
        shouldAdd = true;
}

if (shouldAdd)
    arrayData.add(entry);
```

This approach tips toward being verbose just to float the idea of leaning away from thinking you have to collapse everything into a single `if` statement.  You can have complex per-version logic that sets a variable, and that variable can trigger the ultimate decision.  (In this case your per-version logic is pretty simple, so it's overkill.)

If you cache the result of the type check in a boolean, it will be cheap and avoids potential mistyping of the string constant.  *(And if you're referring to these frequently, you should probably create a global constant... it's easy to miss and get `"tpyeA"` and have no compiler checking to catch the mistake!)*